# Question about combinatorics distribution and set theory

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

### Question

Divide 13 different candies among three students: A, B, and C.
If one person is to receive 7 candies and the other two are to receive 3 candies each, how many different ways can the candies be distributed?

tips:Please calculate by using set language, including the use of counting principles and permutations and combinations, and also use set language.

### Routine procedures

(0)For the distribution problem, we can adopt a strategy of grouping first and then distributing.

(1)First, we use the principle of step-by-step multiplication to divide the 13 candies into three groups. Each step is considered as dividing one group from the 13 candies, which results in:

$$\large C\binom{13}{7} \times C\binom{6}{3} \times C\binom{3}{3}$$

(2)Notice that among the three groups formed, two have the same number of elements. Since there is no order between groups, we need to divide by the permutation of these two groups.

$$\large\dfrac{C\binom{13}{7} \times C\binom{6}{3} \times C\binom{3}{3}} { P\binom{2}{2}}$$

(3)With this, we obtain the number of ways to group.

(4)We just need to arrange the three groups once to get the total number of methods.

$$[\large\dfrac{C\binom{13}{7} \times C\binom{6}{3} \times C\binom{3}{3}} { P\binom{2}{2}} ]P\binom{3}{3}$$

### Confusion

The entire process seems correct, but in fact, when using natural language to logically describe the second step, it's difficult to strictly explain: **Why is it correct to divide by the permutation number of groups with the same number of elements?**

$$
[\large \dfrac{C\binom{13}{7} \times \color{red}{C\binom{6}{3} \times C\binom{3}{3}}}{\color{red}{P\binom{2}{2}}}] {P\binom{3}{3}}
$$

### Discussion

We can observe that what natural language tries to express is: when dividing n different elements into m groups of the same number of elements, there will be a situation of repeated counting. The source of this repetition should be related to the principle of multiplication.

Inspired by @inversioner, I think that using set theory to formalize the principles of multiplication, permutations, permutation numbers, combinations, and combination numbers should provide a strict tool to deduce the answer to this problem.

### Attempt

(1)Define set $A$ to represent the 13 different candies, and $b_1,b_2,b_3$ as three subsets of set $A$ (i.e. non-repeating combinations).

\begin{align}
        A &= \{a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots ,a_{13}\}\\\\
        A &=b_1\cup b_2\cup b_3\\\\
        \forall i \forall j&\in [3] \land (i\neq j)\\\\
        b_i\cap b_j&=\emptyset\\\\
        |b_1|&=7\ \  |b_2|=3\ \ |b_3|=3\\
\end{align}

(2)Then, define the sets of combinations corresponding to the subsets $b_1,b_2,b_3$ as $B_1,B_2,B_3$

\begin{align*}
        B_1 &=\{b_1|b_1\subseteq A \}\\\\
        B_2 &=\{b_2|b_2\subseteq A-b_1 \}\\\\
        B_3 &=\{b_3|b_3\subseteq A-b_1-b_2 \}\\\\
\end{align*}

(3)By the principle of step-by-step multiplication.

\begin{align*}
         B  &=B_1\times B_2\times B_3\\\\
        |B| &=|B_1\times B_2\times B_3|=|B_1|\times |B_2|\times |B_3|\\\\
        &{omission^{[1]}}\\\\
        |X| &= \large(\dfrac{|B|}{P\binom{2}{2}})P\binom{3}{3}\\    
\end{align*}
[1]The steps omitted due to personal capability limitations.

(!)The key question is, "How is set $B$, through a series of operations, transformed into the desired set $X$?"
(!!)Is there someone who can complete the omitted steps?

Comment: Gratitude to those interested in this issue and offering advice and assistance.

Comment: If the candies are different, it should matter which person receives which candies.  We divide by the number of groups of the same size when those groups are unlabeled or indistinguishable.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with division by the number of permutations is that **it does not correspond to a cardinality of any set**. Look at these examples to understand what I mean:

- when you multiply numbers in your answer, it is due to the fact that $\forall A, B\ |A\times B| = |A| \cdot |B|$;
- when you use $C(^n_k)$ in your answer, it is due to the fact that $\forall A, k\ |\mathcal P_k(A)| = C(_{\ \ k}^{|A|})$, where $\mathcal P_k(A)$ is the set of all $k$-element subsets of A (so called *combinations*);
- when you use $n!$ in your answer, it is due to the fact that $\forall A\  |Bij(A, A)| = |A|!$, where $Bij(A, A)$ is the set of all bijections between $A$ and $A$ (so called *permutations*)

and so on. If you have 2 sets $A$ and $B$, then $\dfrac{|A|}{|B|}$ is generally not a cardinality of some other set. That is where your confusion comes from.

To cope with this problem you sould avoid such divisions in your proofs entirely. Here is my solution for the problem. Let $S$ be a set of all students, $C$ be a set of all candy and $\phi$ be an arbitrary bijection between $S$ and $\{0, 1, 2\}$ (basically, we introduce a total order on $S$). Firstly, we choose a student $f$ ($f\in S$), that we will give 7 candies. After that we will choose 7 candies out of 13 ($c_1 \in\mathcal P_7(C)$) to give to $f$. From the remaining 6 candies we will choose 3 ($c_2 \in \mathcal P_3 (C')$. Technically, $C'$ is different for each $c_1$, but $|C'|$ is always $6$, and $|\mathcal P_3(C')|$ is always $C(^6_3)$). We will give these 3 candies to one of the 2 remaining students ($S \backslash \{f\}$) that is *minimal* in respect to $\phi$. The remaining 3 candies will go to the only remaining student. The number of different possibilities to choose the above-mentioned elements is $3 \cdot C(^{13}_7) \cdot C(^6_3) = 102960$. Observe, that this answer is the same as yours.

If you are not convinced that this is a valid proof, it is possible to make it more formal and precise. The task is to find the cardinality of $D = \{f \in S^C\mid \exists s_1, s_2, s_3\ S = \{s_1, s_2, s_3\} \wedge |f^{-1}(s_1)| = 7 \wedge |f^{-1}(s_2)| = |f^{-1}(s_3)| = 3\}$, and the solution would be finding a bijection between $D$ and $S \times \mathcal P_7(C) \times \mathcal P_3(\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5\})$ (this bijection is implicitly described in the informal proof above).